# How to add test files to a linting script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, package.json

I currently have this command in my package.json:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "{src}/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier-eslint --write"
    ]
  }
```

How can I add testing files to this? Currently `SampleComponent.test.tsx` does not get this command invoked on it, but `SampleComponent.tsx` does. Thanks!

Comment: what is location of SampleComponent.test.tsx?

Comment: `SampleComponent.test.tsx` and `SampleComponent.tsx` are in the same folder.

Comment: `{src}/**/*?(.test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`